# How to doxygen comment Qt properties?

Tags: c++, qt, doxygen

I would like to attach Doxygen comments to my Q_PROPERTYs.

For example:

song.h

```
class Song : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

private:
    Q_PROPERTY(QString title READ title WRITE setTitle);
    QString _title;

public:
    QString title() const;
    void setTitle(const QString& value);
};
```

song.cpp

```
#include "song.h"

Song::Song(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
}

QString Song::title() const { return _title; }

void Song::setTitle(const QString &value) { _title = value; }
```

How can I tell Doxygen that title is a property in the Qt Meta-Object system and title() and setTitle() are the accessor functions? I would like to achieve a similar output to [this](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qobject.html#objectName-prop).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have finally found a way to do this.

- In the source files:

  ```
  /**
   * @brief The name of the user.
   * @accessors name(), setName()
   */
  Q_PROPERTY(QString name READ name WRITE setName)
  ```
- In the `Doxyfile`:

  ```
  ALIASES = "accessors=\par Accessors:\n"
  ```

What I've done is define [an alias](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/custcmd.html) named "accessors" that will generate a paragraph with the title "Accessors:" followed by the referenced methods.

Here's what it looks like in the documentation:

[image]

---

**Tip:** if the name of the property is the same as the method for reading the property, you may want to precede the accessor's name in the documentation by a '`%`' (otherwise the accessor will be displayed as a link that points to itself):

```
/**
 * ...
 * @accessors %name(), setName()
 * ...
 */
```

Comment: With latest Doxygen in 2019 (v 1.8.15) I had to use `^^` in place of the `\n` otherwise doxygen gives me an error and puts the functions names on the same line as the paragraph title (and doesn't link them). So it becomes `ALIASES = "accessors=\par Accessors:^^"` BTW, the quotes are important, even if using Doxywizard GUI.

Comment: Another apparent trick... if the prop. name is same as the read accessor, puting a `void` in the accessor name forces a link to the function (instead of the recursive link to itself). So it looks like `@accessors name(void), setName()`. A bit old-fashioned... :)  Wish there was a better way to force it.  Also another useful alias, for separating the notifier signal: `ALIASES += "notifier=\par Notifier signal:^^"`  Used: `@notifier nameChanged()`.

Comment: I have an error if I don't document both the property and it's corresponding accessors. Is it normal?

Answer (score 14):

doxygen supports Qt properties out of the box.  Just add a documentation comment above the property declaration, and you will see a "property" in the doxygen output.

Please note, that the accessor functions will be documented separately, if they also have documentation comments.  You therefore need to remove documentation comments from these accessor functions, if you want to suppress these in the generated documentation.

Answer (score 2):

The doxygen comment in qobject.cpp for objectName property starts with "\property" tag:

```
/*!
    \property QObject::objectName

    \brief the name of this object

    You can find an object by name (and type) using findChild(). You can
    find a set of objects with findChildren().

    \snippet doc/src/snippets/code/src_corelib_kernel_qobject.cpp 5

    By default, this property contains an empty string.

    \sa metaObject(), QMetaObject::className()
*/
```

Have you tried using it? If it doesn't work out of the box, I'd try to find out how Qt generates it's docs - maybe you need some macros/aliases in doxygen configuration.

Comment: Qt does not use doxygen but qdoc to generate its documentation, but doxygen tries to stay reasonably qdoc-compatible.