# doxygen -Qt5 property commenting with accessor

Tags: qt, properties, qt5, documentation, doxygen

I am attempting to use doxygen to comment my Qt5 classes, in particular the Q_PROPERTY macro in the same manner as the Qt5 documentation. This has the property commented, with accessors and notifier if needed. Now I can produce that using [Nathan Osman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/193619/nathan-osman)'s and [Maxim Paperno](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3246449/maxim-paperno)'s hints from [How to doxygen comment Qt properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4914118/how-to-doxygen-comment-qt-properties) however although they show the accessors and notifiers correctly, in Qt5 there is also a link back from the method documentation to the property, i.e. the documentation has a link from text() and setText() to the properties documentation, rather than having their own, which I cannot reproduce.

The doxygen config for these are:

```
      "ALIASES += accessor=\\par Access functions:^^"
      "ALIASES += notifier=\\par Notifier signal:^^"
```

The .h file has the following as property and public method declaration. The two % characters block a link from the property accessor documentation to the method documentation the same way as in Qt. Obviously I have left out a lot of unnecessary stuff from the code..

```
    /*!
      \property MyClass::text
      \brief This property holds the classes's text.

      By default, this property contains an empty string.

      @accessor %text(void), %setText()
    */
    Q_PROPERTY(QString text READ text WRITE setText)

   QString text() const;
   void setText(const QString& text);

   private:
      QString m_text;
```

The cpp code has the following definition

```
    QString MyClass::text() const
    {
       return m_text;
    }

    void MyClass::setText(const QString& text)
    {
       m_text = text;
    }
```

Is there any way to reproduce this with doxygen?

Right thanks @albert  for that. I did mean accessor not accessors a slight bit of finger trouble. Doxygen version is 1.8.17.

I am using doxygen to document some of my custom classes, however in Qt 5.15.0, and 4.8 at least, the documentation as in doxygen consists of lists of properties/methods etc. followed by more detailed documentation.

If there is a property with accessors, then the method in the list section links to the property details, rather than a method detail. However I haven't found a way of making that link using doxygen. The method in the  list section has no link.

There is also a problem with propertied methods with the same property name and accessor name not showing documentation for the method, if you write extra for method. I tried doing it that way earlier.

Comment: Welcome. 1) which version of doxygen are you using.  2) the ALIASES contains `accessors` but the used command is `accessor` 3) I'm not, completely, getting what you mean by "link back" maybe you are looking for commands like `\copydoc` / `\copydetails` / `\copybrief` or placing a `\avnchor` in the property documentation and use `\ref` or `\see` in combination with `\ref` in the description of the accessors.

Comment: the command `\avnchor` should of course read `\anchor`

Comment: Thanks @albert I have edited my question with more details and cleaned up the accessor/accessors miscopy. I don't think copydoc etc. will do what I want (see edits) however thank for those anyway as I was about to copy a bunch of comments from earlier classes and that might help.

Comment: OK now I feel like an idiot. Not certain exactly what I did but I was cleaning up my comments and it started to work correctly.

Comment: Don't feel an idiot, be happy that your problem is solved. The problems are normally made clear / disappear when creating a nice small MWE as at that moment extra care is taken of having a good example. This happens to all of us.